# 'instanceof HandlerMethod' Always Returns false in a Spring Interceptor, Despite Same Class Loader

Tags: spring-boot

I've encountered a peculiar issue while developing a web application using the Spring Framework. I've defined an interceptor to perform some operations before handling a request. However, in the preHandle method of the interceptor, although the handler object is indeed an instance of HandlerMethod, the check handler instanceof HandlerMethod consistently returns false.

Here is the relevant code segment in my interceptor:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    log.info("The specific class name of handler: {}", handler.getClass().getName());
    log.info("Is handler a HandlerMethod class?: {}", (handler instanceof HandlerMethod));
    log.info("The class loader of handler: {}", handler.getClass().getClassLoader());
    log.info("The class loader of HandlerMethod: {}", HandlerMethod.class.getClassLoader());

    if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
        log.info("Request intercepted, request URI: {}", request.getRequestURI());
        return true;
    }

    // Other logic...
    return true;
}
```

In my logs, I can clearly see that the handler object is indeed an instance of the HandlerMethod class, and both handler and HandlerMethod are loaded by the same class loader:

```
The specific class name of handler: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
Is handler a HandlerMethod class?: false
The class loader of handler: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7
The class loader of HandlerMethod: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7
```

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.7.3. I have confirmed the following:

- There is no special configuration related to class loaders in my project.
- I have not included multiple versions of the Spring framework in the project.
  I have a fair understanding of the Spring framework and Java's class loading mechanism, but this is the first time I've encountered this issue, and I'm quite puzzled.

Could anyone provide some possible reasons or solutions? Thank you for your help!